# real & predicted values in kfold

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I'd like a piece of advise!

I use kfold cross validation to split my dataset and evaluate the model for a classification problem.

I need to know if there is a way to **print out the real values** as well as **the corresponded predicted values of each fold,** so i can see what the model predicts in each iteration of kfold.
I'll try to implement this in a small dataset , in order to figure out how it works and then put it in the actual code.

I searched this site and found out another question similar to mine, but it wasn't really helpful

I should probably put those values in an array and use the functions "for" to make a loop and "cross_val_predict" to get the predictions.

Can somebody help please?

Comment: Yes, `cross_val_predict` is exactly doing what you were asking for. The real values you already have from your input data. Not sure what the problem is? Can you share your code and explain what is missing or not working?

Comment: The problem is 
1)that due to the fact that during ΚFold procedure the Test_set changes,so I don't know in what form and how to print the actual label and the corresponded predicted labels. (the classes)
2)Should it be an array? If yes,then what should be the format of eows and columns in  this array?
3)How can I implement this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should give you what you want. You don't need to explicitly go through the indices because `cross_val_predict` gives you the predicted value for all points when they are in the validation set (it automatically handles the k-fold split).

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_predict

X = #features
y = #labels

classifier = SVC(kernel='linear',random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X, y)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)

y_pred = cross_val_predict(classifier, X, y, cv=kfold)

for i in range(len(y)):
   print('Predicted value = ' + str(y_pred[i]))
   print('Real value = ' + str(y[i]))
```

Comment: Yes!This is it!Thank you very much!!

Comment: @LiassaM. Great, glad it worked the way you intended! Btw, you can accept answers to have solved your problem, so other people who have a similar problem can find the solution more easily. :)

Comment: I didn't know it was private :-o ! I'm new to this site so thanks for the tip!

Comment: No worries! Sorry for the confusion, but it's actually not private - it's just easier to see (before clicking the title) that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Those are some of the parts in my test code, for dinary classification with 20 samples an 2 features:

```
         #Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
```

Input

```
:for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

Output:
 TRAIN: [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19] TEST: [2 3]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19] TEST: [4 5]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19] TEST: [6 7]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19] TEST: [8 9]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19] TEST: [10 11]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 14 15 16 17 18 19] TEST: [12 13]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 16 17 18 19] TEST: [14 15]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 18 19] TEST: [16 17]
TRAIN: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17] TEST: [18 19]
```

#Training the SVM model on the Training set

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier=SVC(kernel='linear',random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

#Predicting the Test set results

```
Input:  y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)     print(np.concatenate((y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1),y_test.reshape(len(y_test),1)),1))
Output: [[1 1]
         [1 0]]
```

how can I have the actual values next to predictesd values in every iteration of kfold,as the output in #Predicting the Test set results ?